# FileStream writing files with all NULLs

Tags: c#, sql, filestream

I need to retrieve a varbinary column from SQL Server and write it out to files.  So far I have gotten 1 successful file back (a .tif) and another .pdf that seemed to work at first (albeit with some complaining by Adobe) but ultimately refused to ever open again.

I am getting files that *appear* to have normal sizes but when I open them in something like Notepad or a hex editor they are just full of NUL (notepad) or 00 in the hex editor.  The files will not open in Adobe or whatever normally opens a jpg or tif in Windows.  The code I'm using is borrowed nearly verbatim from here on SO...I am not sure where the problem is but I am not really a programmer and don't know the inner workings of files/buffers etc.  Appreciate any help you can provide.

```
         using (conn)
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var sqlQueryResult = sqlQuery.ExecuteReader())
                if (sqlQueryResult != null)
                {
                        while(sqlQueryResult.Read())
                        {
                            var subfolder = sqlQueryResult[0].ToString();
                            var createFile = sqlQueryResult[1].ToString();
                            var blob = new Byte[(sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(2, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
                            Console.WriteLine($"{subfolder}\\{createFile}");
                            Console.WriteLine("Byte Length:");
                            Console.WriteLine(blob.Length);
                            //sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(0, 0, blob, 0, blob.Length);
                            Directory.CreateDirectory($"E:\\xxxxx\\{subfolder}");
                            using (var fs = new FileStream($"E:\\xxxxx\\{subfolder}\\{createFile}", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                            {
                                fs.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
                                //fs.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    //sqlQueryResult.Read();

                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure the data is correct in SQL? Also, doubtful it's a fix to the problem, but you can just do `File.WriteAllBytes(path, blob);` instead of all that `FileStream` business. One more thing, `Path.Combine` is really the preferred way to put different pieces of a file path together.

Comment: Have you checked what `var blob = new Byte[(sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(2, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];` actually is? It's a byte array initialized with the length of the field content, while the content (the Buffer, your `null` parameter) is discarded. Btw, you don't exactly need that method, but in case you want to use it, see the remarks section of [SqlDataReader.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes)

Comment: Thanks @Jimi - I have normally used the `System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess` when doing this task but since I just "borrowed" this code I did not have it here.  It did not seem to make a difference here.

Comment: @itsme86 I had one .tif that seemed to be good - i don't know how much of an inference I can make from that about the remainder.  I know when I look in SQL Server itself the fields **LOOK** like they're a lot more than just 0000000...Maybe i just need to try this BCP approach I see people taking for this sometimes.  It looks like a bit of a pain.

Comment: *Make a difference*? Your `blob`, in `var blob = new Byte[(sqlQueryResult.GetBytes(2, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];` is just an empty byte array (so, initialized with all `byte.MinValue` values, AKA `0`). The third parameter of `GetBytes()`, which should be the Buffer that receives the content, you are discarding it. `GetBytes()` returns just the length of the buffer read.

Comment: @Jimii Oh NOW I get what you're saying.  That's why I was seeing all zeroes...switching to `var blob = (byte[])sqlQueryResult[2];` resolves that, but the files are still not usable.  The database also provides the expected size of these, and that matches the byte array length in 90% or more of the cases.  I've noticed that BCP-produced files have the same problem...so maybe the data is just bad in the table.  Thanks for straightening me out on the other things though.

Comment: You need to show the procedure that stored the binaries into your database.

Comment: BTW, `using (var fs = new FileStream(...) { ... }` is the same as `File.WriteAllBytes([Array Content])` (just to simplify the code)

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for the tips, but I don't have access to whatever wrote these in the first place.  I think that you solved the part of the problem I had created for myself by incorrectly using `GetBytes()`.  The problem with the output files not opening may not be solvable here.  I think your second comment was my ah-hah moment so that is probably the answer here...